# "Have" versus "Had"

Tags: modal-verbs, past-simple, present-simple

> They **could** easily win the game.

Which of the following two sentences has a similar meaning to the sentence above? To me, the first one looks the most logical because "could" refers to something that happened in the past, therefore "had" is more appropriate.

> They **had** a good chance of winning.
>
> They **have** a good chance of winning.

Comment: *Could* has two senses.  One is the past tense of *can*, used like "I *could* fit in that closet when I was much younger and smaller, but I can't now.*  The other is to express current or future possibility: "I *could* go to the park today, if I wanted to."

Comment: *Had* is past tense, which would change could to *could have*. Using simply *could* implies the game is still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the most similar form would be

> They **have** a good chance of winning

This is because in your initial sentence

> They could easily win

suggests that they have not yet won.

---

On the other hand, if you express your initial sentence in a perfected past, then you would have.

> The could have easily won

Then it would be appropriate to use the past.

> They **had** a good chance of winning